# Symfony sfDoctrinePager with multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, symfony1, doctrine, pager

I was wondering how to get this to run. In my application I have a Category table and Product table. I need to have a pager which combines both Categories and Products for display in one list (first categories then products). Is there a way to get this going ? I tried left joining in the pager's query, but doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: May we take a look at code? Controller, view and anything related. And schema too. If you don't mind, I'd prefer http://gist.github.com/

Comment: Ok so here's the deal ... pastebin.com/TyUQUVMt I've written the details below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i did to solve this was to write my own pager which extended the sfDoctrinePager and the created methods which give results in an array from 2 queries. Had to do some extra writting but worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you can write a doctrine query to return the complete list of what you want, then the pager will page it.

Not sure without a schema how you might write such a query, not even 100% sure what you want to do. But if you are trying to list products with related category info, then you'll be needing a join, else if you want a mixed list of categories and products, you'll probably be wanting a UNION query.

If you post a schema and a bit more info about what you are doing, can try to help you.

Comment: Ok so here's the deal ... http://pastebin.com/TyUQUVMt

If i go to a category page, I want a pager to be displayed with:
- Selected Category's subcategories (first)
- Selected Category's products (then) 

All in one pager. Basically results from two tables together in one pager and subcategories come first in the results.

Comment: I'd start by writing a doctrine query that can do this, or an sql one. You probably need to look at unions, and it may be a bit hacky as not sure that doctrine can handle one query returning two types of object maybe hydrating as an array will work though