# How to use doctrine or symfony pager with different column selected from multiple table?

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, doctrine-1.2

**How can I implement pagination using Doctrine_Pager or sfDoctrinePager while my query selects multiple columns from two or more tables ?**

---

**Edit1:**

Ok, now I figured out that it can be done how Nathan has described below! I got confused as I couldn't retrieve certain data from the query! Let me describe it below:

This is my pager query:

```
        $pager = new sfDoctrinePager('sfGuardUser', '5'); 

        $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
                        ->select('u.id, u.username,  p.org_name,  g.name, l.status')
                        ->from('sfGuardUser u')
                        ->leftJoin('u.Profile p')
                        ->leftJoin('u.Groups g')
                        ->leftJoin('u.LicensedVendors l')
                        ->where('g.name = \'client\'');

        $pager->setQuery($q);
        $pager->setPage($request->getParameter('page', 1));
        $pager->init();
```

Now in my Template I can retrieve my sfGuardUser and Profile data like this:

```
 foreach ($pager->getResults() as $data) {


            echo $data->username ;  //outputs 'username' from sfGuardUser table
            echo '<br />' ;
            echo $data->Profile->org_name ; //outputs 'Organization name' from sfGuardUserProfile table 

}
```

I was wrongly trying to retrieve the profile data by `$data->org_name` and not `$data->Profile->org_name`! Now its working for this part correctly, **but there is still an issue** !

I am still unable to retrieve the **Groups** & **LicensedVendors** data using `$data->Groups->name` or `$data->LicensedVendors->status` ! It does not show any error or any value either! looks like it outputs an empty string. Shouldn't it get the value just like Profile data ? 
But when I `hydrate` the query by setting:

`$q->setHydrationMode(Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_SCALAR);`

I can retrieve all data through:

```
foreach ($pager->getResults() as $data) {

      echo $data['u_username'];
      echo $data['p_org_name'];
      echo $data['g_name'];
      echo $data['l_status'];
}
```

*How to get those data without setting `**Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_SCALAR**` ? Where I'm doing wrong for retrieving those **Groups** and **LicensedVendors** table data?*

Here is the schema definition of the tables described above:

```
License:
  actAs: [Timestampable]
  tableName: licenses
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(4)
      primary: true
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: true
    status:
      type: enum
      values: ['approved','pending_admin','pending_client','pending_vendor','rejected']
      default: 'pending'
    client_id:
      type: integer(8)
      notnull: true
    vendor_id:
      type: integer(8)
      notnull: true
    product_desc:
      type: clob(16777215)
    supplier_name:
      type: string(80)
    other_desc:
      type: string(50)
    financial_statement:
      type: clob
  relations:
    VendorUser:
      class: sfGuardUser
      local: client_id
      foreign: id
      foreignAlias: LicensedVendors
      onDelete: cascade
      foreignType: many
      owningSide: true
    ClientUser:
      class: sfGuardUser
      local: vendor_id
      foreign: id
      foreignAlias: LicensedClients
      onDelete: cascade
      foreignType: many
      owningSide: true


sfGuardUser:
      actAs: [Timestampable]
      columns:
        first_name: string(255)
        last_name: string(255)
        email_address:
          type: string(255)
          notnull: true
          unique: true
        username:
          type: string(128)
          notnull: true
          unique: true
        algorithm:
          type: string(128)
          default: sha1
          notnull: true
        salt: string(128)
        password: string(128)
        is_active:
          type: boolean
          default: 1
        is_super_admin:
          type: boolean
          default: false
        last_login:
          type: timestamp
      indexes:
        is_active_idx:
          fields: [is_active]
      relations:
        Groups:
          class: sfGuardGroup
          local: user_id
          foreign: group_id
          refClass: sfGuardUserGroup
          foreignAlias: Users

sfGuardUserProfile:
  actAs:
    Timestampable: ~
  columns:
    user_id:
      type: integer
      notnull: true
    email:
      type: string(80)
      notnull: true
      unique: true
    email_new:
      type: string(80)
      unique: true
    firstname:
      type: string(30)
    lastname:
      type: string(70)
    org_name:
      type: string(80)
      notnull: true

  relations:
    User:
      class: sfGuardUser
      foreign: id
      local: user_id
      type: one
      onDelete: cascade
      foreignType: one
      foreignAlias: Profile




sfGuardGroup:
  actAs: [Timestampable]
  columns:
    name:
      type: string(255)
      unique: true
    description: string(1000)
  relations:
    Users:
      class: sfGuardUser
      refClass: sfGuardUserGroup
      local: group_id
      foreign: user_id
      foreignAlias: Groups
```

---

**Edit2:** I posted my new issues which I described in first edit as a separate question [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448823/retrieving-doctrine-data-from-sfdoctrinepager-object) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, what greg0ire said.  [This documentation is a bit old](http://www.symfony-project.org/askeet/1_0/en/5#chapter_05_question_pager), but it shows what you'd need with Propel in the old days.  Updating to Doctrine would be like,

```
public function executeList ()
{
  $pager = new sfDoctrinePager('Comment', 2);

  $q = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Comment')
    ->createQuery('c')
    ->where('c.author = ?', 'Steve')
    ->leftJoin('c.Article a')
    ->andWhere('a.content LIKE ?', '%enjoy%')
    ->orderBy('c.created_at ASC');

  $pager->setQuery($q);
  $pager->setPage($request->getParameter('page', 1));
  $pager->init();

  $this->pager = $pager;
}
```

[This blog post, "Symfony doctrine pager for two tables"](http://blog.karolsojko.com/index.php/2010/08/symfony-doctrine-pager-for-two-tables/) has a more extended/convoluted example.  Oh, looks like that was the author's answer to [his own SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362327/symfony-sfdoctrinepager-with-multiple-tables).

Comment: Thanks Nathan for your answer! It should work the way you put it above; after trying for a while I have figured out the problem. I actually need to retrieve the data in a different fashion. However there is still an issue which I have put elaborately in my edited part of the question! You can have a look at it :)

Comment: medhad, your original question was clear and I tried to answer it clearly.  With your edits, it is a totally different thing.  Maybe you should ask a new question.  I'm wondering if you really need the joins before you set up the pager?  Can't you do `$license->getVendorUser()` as you loop through the pager results?

Comment: Nathan, you are right about posting it as a new question! I just asked it in a new thread and scraped from here!
I can get the user(vendor) by *$license->getVendorsUser* true, but in this case I need to query all users who are in client group and also their corresponding license status with the current vendor!

Answer (score 1):

I guess as long as your query gives back a Doctrine_Collection object, you can use it with a pager, can't you?

Comment: Hi actually you are right! But I was having problem in retrieving the data from pager! I just figured out that to get the joined table's column data, I need to write some code differently!