# Retrieving doctrine data from sfDoctrinePager object !

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

I am facing some issues while retrieving data from a doctrine pager object!
Let me describe it below:

This is my pager query:

```
        $pager = new sfDoctrinePager('sfGuardUser', '5'); 

        $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
                        ->select('u.id, u.username,  p.org_name,  g.name, l.status')
                        ->from('sfGuardUser u')
                        ->leftJoin('u.Profile p')
                        ->leftJoin('u.Groups g')
                        ->leftJoin('u.LicensedVendors l')
                        ->where('g.name = \'client\'');

        $pager->setQuery($q);
        $pager->setPage($request->getParameter('page', 1));
        $pager->init();
```

Now in my Template I can retrieve my sfGuardUser and Profile data like this:

```
 foreach ($pager->getResults() as $data) {


            echo $data->username ;  //outputs 'username' from sfGuardUser table
            echo '<br />' ;
            echo $data->Profile->org_name ; //outputs 'Organization name' from sfGuardUserProfile table 

}
```

But I am still unable to retrieve the **Groups** & **LicensedVendors** data using `$data->Groups->name` or `$data->LicensedVendors->status` ! It does not show any error or any value either! looks like it outputs an empty string. Shouldn't it get the value just like Profile data ?

However, when I `hydrate` the query by setting:

`$q->setHydrationMode(Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_SCALAR);`

I can retrieve all data through:

```
foreach ($pager->getResults() as $data) {

      echo $data['u_username'];
      echo $data['p_org_name'];
      echo $data['g_name'];
      echo $data['l_status'];
}
```

*How to get those data without setting `**Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_SCALAR**` ? Where I'm doing wrong for retrieving those **Groups** and **License** table data as an object?*

Here is the schema definition of the tables described above:

```
License:
  actAs: [Timestampable]
  tableName: licenses
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(4)
      primary: true
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: true
    status:
      type: enum
      values: ['approved','pending_admin','pending_client','pending_vendor','rejected']
      default: 'pending'
    client_id:
      type: integer(8)
      notnull: true
    vendor_id:
      type: integer(8)
      notnull: true
    product_desc:
      type: clob(16777215)
    supplier_name:
      type: string(80)
    other_desc:
      type: string(50)
    financial_statement:
      type: clob
  relations:
    ClientUser:
      class: sfGuardUser
      local: client_id
      foreign: id
      foreignAlias: LicensedVendors
      onDelete: cascade
      foreignType: many
      owningSide: true
    VendorUser:
      class: sfGuardUser
      local: vendor_id
      foreign: id
      foreignAlias: LicensedClients
      onDelete: cascade
      foreignType: many
      owningSide: true


sfGuardUser:
      actAs: [Timestampable]
      columns:
        first_name: string(255)
        last_name: string(255)
        email_address:
          type: string(255)
          notnull: true
          unique: true
        username:
          type: string(128)
          notnull: true
          unique: true
        algorithm:
          type: string(128)
          default: sha1
          notnull: true
        salt: string(128)
        password: string(128)
        is_active:
          type: boolean
          default: 1
        is_super_admin:
          type: boolean
          default: false
        last_login:
          type: timestamp
      indexes:
        is_active_idx:
          fields: [is_active]
      relations:
        Groups:
          class: sfGuardGroup
          local: user_id
          foreign: group_id
          refClass: sfGuardUserGroup
          foreignAlias: Users

sfGuardUserProfile:
  actAs:
    Timestampable: ~
  columns:
    user_id:
      type: integer
      notnull: true
    email:
      type: string(80)
      notnull: true
      unique: true
    email_new:
      type: string(80)
      unique: true
    firstname:
      type: string(30)
    lastname:
      type: string(70)
    org_name:
      type: string(80)
      notnull: true

  relations:
    User:
      class: sfGuardUser
      foreign: id
      local: user_id
      type: one
      onDelete: cascade
      foreignType: one
      foreignAlias: Profile


sfGuardGroup:
  actAs: [Timestampable]
  columns:
    name:
      type: string(255)
      unique: true
    description: string(1000)
  relations:
    Users:
      class: sfGuardUser
      refClass: sfGuardUserGroup
      local: group_id
      foreign: user_id
      foreignAlias: Groups
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the ArrayAccess.

meaning

```
 foreach ($pager->getResults() as $data) {


        echo $data['username'] ;  //outputs 'username' from sfGuardUser table
        echo '<br />' ;
        echo $data['Profile'][0]['org_name'] ; //outputs 'Organization name' from sfGuardUserProfile table
```

Or maybe the problem is the lacking [0] in your code, meaning

```
 echo $data->Profile[0]->org_name ; //outputs 'Organization name' from sfGuardUserProfile table
```

Comment: You pointed it out pretty right Waleed! **echo $data->LicensedVendors[0]->status** now giving me results! but still its acting differently than expected! According to query it brings 4 table data where for 'status' field its like 'approved', 'pending', NULL, NULL ! The **echo $data['l_status']** code behaves as expected, but **echo $data->LicensedVendors[0]->status** outputs: 'approved', 'pending', 'pending', 'pending' ! so it outputs 'pending' for last 2 NULL value ! isn't it strange?